# CSS :hover transform scale command rotate object instead

Tags: css, hover, transform, scale

```css
.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-top: solid black 2.5px;
  border-left: solid black 2.5px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.arrow::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  margin-left: -3px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  border-top: solid black 1.8px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.arrow:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<span class="arrow"></span>
```

I draw an arrow using css and try to create a hover scale up effect by using css :hover and transform:scale. However the codes rotate the arrow first and then scale it up later. I am wondering why is rotating happening and how do I fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have an obvious rotate css propperty there that is applied to the whole element. You need to take in account to rotate against it while hovering over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-top: solid black 2.5px;
  border-left: solid black 2.5px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.arrow::before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  margin-left: -3px;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
  border-top: solid black 1.8px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.arrow:hover {
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.2);
  transform: rotate(-45deg) scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<span class="arrow"></span>
```

the problem is that **transform properties don't sum up**, if you override a property and want to keep it's original value you need to repeat it.

Answer (score 3):

Use this CSS for hover:

```
.arrow:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-45deg);
  transform: scale(1.2) rotate(-45deg);
}
```

Rotate was set on the entire element and was not accounted for during the hover transform.

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ozknys63/) is a working example

Answer (score 0):

You can give transform only to `:before` so it won't rotate on hover.

```css
.arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1px;
  width: 18px;
  border-top: solid black 1.8px;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.arrow:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: -10px;
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  border-top: solid black 2.5px;
  border-left: solid black 2.5px;
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s;
  -moz-transition: transform 1s;
  transition: transform 1s;
  cursor: pointer;
position: relative;
top: -9px;
}
.arrow:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<span class="arrow"></span>
```